# Running a node command in harmony irrespective of OS

Tags: node.js, windows, operating-system, ecmascript-harmony

So for a *nix machine, it is possible to define a script like so:

```
scripts: {
  "unit-test": "node --harmony `which jest` --config jest-unit.json"
}
```

This fails on Windows 10 as the `which` command is not platform agnostic.

Is there a way to do this as a script that works on both windows AND *nix?
And if not, what would the windows script look like?

Comment: Does it work if you just do `jest` with no `which`? I think npm will set the PATH for you.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '/Users/abe/github/project/path/jest'

Comment: And you have Jest in your `package.json` dependencies or devDependencies and installed?

Comment: yes I do, undef devDependencies

Comment: does it work if you install it globally? and run without `which`